# Count SQL query PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I want to count for each gallery number of images in it, here's my query:

```
$req = db_query("SELECT count(*) FROM node,node_file WHERE node.nid = node_file.nid AND nid = ".$value['nid']);
```

here's the two tables :

 node_file:

```
nid  |fid   |
-------------
  1  |  1   | 
-------------
  1  |  2   |  
-------------
  1  |  3   |
-------------
  2  |  1   |
-------------
  2  |  2   |
-------------
  2  |  3   |
```

node:

```
 nid |type  |
-------------
  1  |Gallery1| 
-------------
  2  |gallery2|
```

The error : `Query : SELECT count(*) FROM node,node_file WHERE node.nid = node_file.nid AND nid = 34
Message : SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'nid' in where clause is ambiguous`

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both of your tables have column `nid` and you are using column in `AND` clause so you need to specify to which table it belongs.

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM
    node,
    node_file
WHERE
    node.nid = node_file.nid AND node.nid = 34
```

**OR**

```
SELECT 
    count(*)
FROM
    node,
    node_file
WHERE
    node.nid = node_file.nid AND node_file.nid = 34
```

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
$req = db_query("SELECT count(*) FROM node,node_file WHERE node.nid = node_file.nid AND node.nid = ".$value['nid']);
```